# helm check for required variables in a single file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'd like to have a file that checks for all "required" variables. So far I came up with this, but it doesn't look like this is "best" practices

**values.yaml**

```
# this is required name of the hosted zone
domainZone: "" 
someOtherRequireVar: ""
```

**/templates/required.yaml**

```
# the block below makes sure that our required variables are 
# declared in the values file and if not that will throw the error
# so even the block below is commeted, it's still evaluated by the HELM and error
# will be generated if the variable's value is not set
# {{ .Values.domainZone | required "Domain Zone is required and should be non-empty string" }}
# {{ .Values.someOtherRequireVar | required "The someOtherRequireVar is also required and should be non-empty string" }}
```

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using named templates for validation, which you can execute in your installation notes instead of regular template files.  Furthermore, by using failsafe validation functions (unlike `require`) for individual values, you can validate multiple values before failing execution of your `helm` command.

[Bitnami charts](https://github.com/bitnami/charts) use this strategy.

### Setup

In a [partials file](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#partials-and-_-files), e.g. `templates/_helpers.tpl`, define named templates for validating the supplied values:

```yaml
{{/* Compile all validation warnings into a single message and call fail. */}}
{{- define "mychart.validateValues" -}}
{{- $messages := list -}}
{{- $messages = append $messages (include "mychart.validateValues.foo" .) -}}
{{- $messages = append $messages (include "mychart.validateValues.bar" .) -}}
{{- $messages = without $messages "" -}}
{{- $message := join "\n" $messages -}}

{{- if $message -}}
{{- printf "\nVALUES VALIDATION:\n%s" $message | fail -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{/* Validate value of foo */}}
{{- define "mychart.validateValues.foo" -}}
{{- if not (and .Values.foo (kindIs "string" .Values.foo)) -}}
mychart: foo
    `foo` is required and should be a non-empty string
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{/* Validate the value of bar */}}
{{- define "mychart.validateValues.bar" -}}
{{- if not (and .Values.bar (kindIs "string" .Values.bar)) -}}
mychart: bar
    `bar` is required and should be a non-empty string
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

In this case, the named template `mychart.validateValues` will run multiple validations (i.e. `mychart.validateValues.foo`, `mychart.validateValues.bar`). If one or more validations produce a validation warning, it will call [`fail`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#fail) with a summary of the warnings.

In [`templates/NOTES.txt`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/notes_files/), evaluate the named template for validation:

```yaml
{{- include "mychart.validateValues" . }}
```

### Test

With the following `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
bar: 24
```

Templating, installing, or upgrading the chart will fail with the following message:

```
Error: execution error at (test/templates/NOTES.txt:1:4): 
VALUES VALIDATION:
mychart: foo
    `foo` is required and should be a non-empty string
mychart: bar
    `bar` is required and should be a non-empty string
```